# Show message when Hibernate losses it's connection

Tags: java, hibernate, swing

I have a Hibernate J2SE Swing application and I would like to show user a MessageBox saying that the connection could not be established when the internet connection or the network is having troubles. I know the exception that needs to be caught -

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

But Hibernate has already handled this exception internally. So what do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implmenent your own [ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html).
Basically whenever Hibernate needs a database connection it calls *getConnection()* on its configured ConnectionProvider.

you could create a subclass of the ConnectionProvider you are currently using and do something like that:

```
public class MyConnectionProvider extends WhateverConnectionProviderYouAreUsing
  {
      public Connection getConnection()
      {
           try
           {
               return super.getConnection();
           } 
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               // Show message about connection error
           }
       }
```

In the SessionFactory configuration you have to configure your custom ConnectionProvider like

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=your.packagename.MyConnectionProvider
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to handle it.